# Evernote/Ruby on Rails: How do I create a new NoteFilter and NotesMetadataResultSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, evernote

Hi I'm trying to fetch notes from my Evernote notebook for my Rails app using https://github.com/cgs/evernote. I can fetch individual notes fine but I'm having a problem using findNotesMetadata because I don't know how to create a new **NoteFilter** or **NotesMetadataResultSpec** using this gem or the ruby wrappers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
noteFilter = Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NoteFilter.new
```

You can then populate the attributes like so

```
noteFilter.tagGuids = ["<tag guid>"]
```